# Running script on Compute Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Pardon me, this is more of well optimize way of implementing a task.

Wrote a script to stream file from a url, and save it on my cloud bucket. However, I made it a startup script. So, after the instance is created, it runs the script.
got help from [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/compute-getting-started-python) .

Using google-client-python , the snippet below creates the script :

```
compute.instances().insert(
                project=project,
                zone=zone,
                body=config).execute()
```

The thing is I want to run this script periodically (Using appengine cron). I can get the instance :

```
compute.instances().get(
                project=project,
                zone=zone,
                instance=name).execute()
```

It is possible to rerun the script on getting the instance ? My initial approach was to create a new instance anytime I want to run the script, and delete the instance there after. What approach would be more optimal for me and how do I get the instance to run the new script? Thanks.